# trying to display database content using listAdapter

Tags: java, android, database, cursor, listadapter

I am trying to display a list of contact names for an addressbook app I am creating, but when I run it, it just crashes and I get no log or error/runtime messages.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //TextView list = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        //contentProvider(list);

        String[] columns = new String[]
                {
                        MyDatabase.MyContacts._ID,
                        MyDatabase.MyContacts.Column_NameName,
                };

        String colToDisplay [] = new String[]
                {
                        MyCProviderContract.NAME
                };

        int[] colId = new int[]
                {
                        R.id.listView
                };

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor c = cr.query(MyCProviderContract.CONTENT_URI, columns, MyDatabase.MyContacts.Column_NameName + "=0", null, null);
        c.close();

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_main, c,colToDisplay, colId, 1);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        Button add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainContacts.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        });
    }
```

and the xml file;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/contacts2"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you know where it crashes? Have you tried running it in a debugger or inserting progress checkpoints to narrow down where the problem is?

Comment: Read screen layout part : [ListActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html). whenever you extend `ListActivity` your layout must have `ListView` with `@android:id/list` Id

Answer (score 0):

The layout that you are setting in the activity needs to have a list view init.

Create a different layout for the activity and put a listview in it with `android:id="@+id/list"`

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_view);
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use different layouts for your `Activity` and `Adapter`

And when you extend [ListActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

> your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list"

Check out official doc [ListActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) and you will find an example also.